# how to obtain WindowsIdentity from Negotiate HTTP header value

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, windows-authentication

I am working on securing some REST services and I want to support Windows Authentication.  When the HTTP client has sent no authentication credentials my service responds with an Unauthorized response and a WWAuthenticate value of 'Negotiate'.  This prompts the browser to pop a username and password dialog box.  I enter my windows credentials and the request comes back to my service.  This time there is an Authorization header with a Negotiate scheme that has a value which I assume is some form of my windows identity.  How can I take this header value and translate it into a WindowsIdentity object (or some other object that lets me know who the authenticated user is)?

Edit:  My logic is actually occurring in a http handler higher up in the webapi pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebAPI2 you can do

```
       request.GetRequestContext().Principal.Identity
```

otherwise you can dig the principle out of the Properties dictionary on the request message.

Comment: I'm actually looking to parse the negotiate token myself, (I assume by talking to AD?), and not rely on IIS to translate it into the Identity for me.

Comment: @user2719430 You can easily get access to the auth headers in a messagehandler.  Then you can set the Prinicpal yourself.  I'd love to see that code if you manage to do Windows Auth yourself.

Comment: Performing the windows auth myself is actually what I was trying to ask for in my question.  I've found the materials available on this to be sparse, but it is probably a result of not knowing exactly what to search for.

Comment: @user2719430, did you ever get a solution to this? I'm interesting in doing the same.

Comment: I did not, and documentation on the matter is sparse.

Answer (score -1):

The Controller has a User property which can be used to get the name:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

User.identity is a System.Security.Principal.Identity.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot that I am actually doing this in a http handler higher up in the pipeline.